# pymongo aggregate don't allow explain option

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, explain

I succesfully run:

```
result = my_col.aggregate(my_pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Now when I try:

```
result = my_col.aggregate(my_pipeline, allowDiskUse=True, explain=True)
```

it fails saying:

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The explain option is not supported. Use Database.command instead.
```

Thus I try so as to add the needed option:

```
result = mydb.command('aggregate', 'mycol', my_pipeline, {'explain':True})
```

but it fails saying:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: 'pipeline' option must be specified as an array
```

What is wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

Christian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass your pipeline using the "pipeline" keyword argument to "command":

```
db.command('aggregate', 'mycol', pipeline=my_pipeline, explain=True)
```

For example:

```
db.command('aggregate', 'mycol', pipeline=[{'$project': {'name': '$field'}}], explain=True)
```

Comment: how to get execution stats? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253108/pymongo-aggregate-how-to-get-executionstats