# PyMongo Aggregate how to get executionStats

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to get executionStats of a Particular mongo aggregate query. I run db.command but that doesn't give "execution status"

This is what I am trying to do.
[how to get Python Mongo Aggregate explain using db.command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255968/how-to-get-python-mongo-aggregate-explain-using-db-command)

[pymongo aggregate don't allow explain option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677161/pymongo-aggregate-dont-allow-explain-option)

Comment: Which version of PyMongo and MongoDB ?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
db.command(
    'explain', 
    {
        'aggregate': coll_name, 
        'pipeline': your_pipeline, 
        'cursor': {}
    }, 
    verbosity='executionStats'
)
```