# how to get Python Mongo Aggregate explain using db.command?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

> Starting with MongoDB 3.2 explain() uses the default verbosity mode of
>   the explain command, allPlansExecution. To use a different verbosity
>   use command() to run the explain command directly.

My aggregate query looks something like this

```
collection.aggregate(pipeline=QUERY, explain=True)
```

This returns `queryPlanner` verbose and not `executionStats`.

What mongo shell supports?

```
db.Item_Process_For_Report.explain("executionStats").aggregate([])
```

What am I trying to do?

```
db.command('explain', <What goes here>)
```

Comment: If all you need is to get the explain output: `db.command('aggregate', 'things', pipeline=pipeline, explain=True)` as shown [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework)

Comment: That gives me the `QueryPlanner` not the `executionStats`

Comment: pymongo allows explain only via `db.command` and this internally uses the [Aggregation Command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) and Aggregation this way only allows a bool specification which defaults to `QueryPlanner` as seen [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate)

Comment: That's right. but this `db.Item_Process_For_Report.explain("executionStats").aggregate([])` gives me the execution stats when ran in mongo shell. Too bad we can't do that with pymongo

Answer (score 0):

**As on 22-May-2019 with MongoDB 4.0**

pymongo currently allows explain only via [db.command()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command) and this internally uses the [Aggregation Command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-aggregation/) and Aggregation which limits explain to a Boolean switch which defaults to QueryPlanner as seen [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate)